# Disable show path with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How can I disable the output title that Shows name of folder path

If I put the code In .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
```

I get
Access forbidden!
I just want to cancel the title
That Showing the location of the folder

Example:

```
Index of /script/Upload-master/
```

Within this folder have image files  I still have yet to see them

Comment: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/security-with-htaccess.html

<Files ~ "^.ht">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>

Comment: Try this : http://viralpatel.net/blogs/htaccess-directory-listing-enable-disable-allow-deny-prevent-htaccess-directory-listing/

Answer (score 1):

I think [this article](http://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/) might be helpful. Most of all - *Step 4: Accessing and Modifying Markup*. Add to your HTAccess file:

```
# SET INDEX OPTIONS
IndexOptions SuppressHTMLPreamble

# SPECIFY HEADER FILE
HeaderName header.html
```

Then in the same directory of HTAccess file you create **header.html** with code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
```

It should work. `Options -Indexes` directive, which you have used before, disables directory listings, so you shouldn't use it.

Comment: I do not want to cancel
directory listings
Only the title shows the name of the folder http://oi39.tinypic.com/53649j.jpg

Comment: The last sentence was to explain you what `Options -Indexes` does. But rest of code will give you desired effect. Have you tried it before you comment?